# SQL: how to add condition, where some characters have same value

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables: "table1" and "table2" and in these tables, I have hundred of names. Now I want to select only these names, where first 4 character have the same value.

So far it is not so difficult. Something like this:

```
select * from table1
join table2 on LEFT(table1.name,4)=LEFT(table2.name,4)
```

But I am struggling to add one condition that some characters have same value, for example: i=y, v=w, c=k and vice versa.

If table1 has name "Citty" and table2 has name "Kitty", I want this name also comes out in results

Comment: This isn't a programming question.   It's a business logic question.   Figure out what you want your business rule to be and the coding will be easy.

Comment: If those character equivalents are universal in your use case you could just use the Replace function on the name in either table1 or table2 in your comparison.

Comment: Please explain *why* you are needing to do this. Why 4 characters? Is that an arbitrary number you decided? Do you only care about English?

Comment: you would have to replace those values in BOTH columns, not just one, then compare

Comment: Yes, I re-read and realized I was thinking of values, not columns.   So never mind, you are correct.

Comment: 4 characters is an arbitrary number. Lets say that I compare thousand of string from two different tables and I have to find similar strings. I use difference function and right/left function to get more accurate result. But my problem is that some names are written using i instead of y, I dont want to rule out these names using right/left function after "where clause"(LEFT(table1,1)=LEFT(table2,1).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [SOUNDEX() and DIFFERENCE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) functions of SQL Server. These are available with full text search.

Alternatively, you can create a clr function and call it from sql.